# PDF compression automatically with TeXWorks or WinEdt in Windows 7?

Tags: pdf, texworks, winedt

Currently I use TeXWorks or WinEdt to generate my PDF then open a command window and execute the following to compress the file:

```
>gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile="file_out.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "file.pdf"
```

Is there a way to automatically include this into the build PDF functions of either TeXWorks or WinEdt? It's a trivial extra step, but one I would like to omit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple in WinEdt.

I'm assuming you have the latest version installed (9.0) and you're using pdflatex for compiling.

Go to "Options" -> "Options Interface" -> "Advanced Configuration" -> "Compile Macros" and double-click the "PDFLaTeX" item:

[image]

A local copy of `PDFLaTeX.edt` gets opened. In this file, after the line

```
  Exe('%b\Exec\ExeCompiler.edt');
```

add the following lines

```
  IfFileExists(`%P\%N.pdf`,>
    !`WinExe('','gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile="%N_out.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "%N.pdf"','%P','',011100);`);
```

and then save the file.

Next time you compile a file with pdflatex, you will have your `file.pdf` and the compressed `file_out.pdf` in the same directory.

[image]